# LSTM non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have this code to predict `"Units_Sold"` by each drug type separately, by using RNN LSTM model. For example the output should say paracetamol predicted sales is 30, amoxicilin predicted sales is 31 etc. Here I have provided only few rows of the dataset

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

# Define the dataset
data = [
    ['paracetamol', '2022-01-24', 32, 5.2, 350, 'liquid'],
    ['paracetamol', '2022-01-25', 30, 2.3, 500, 'tablet'],
    ['amoxicilin', '2022-01-26', 34, 3.2, 100, 'injection'],
    ['pregablin', '2022-01-27', 47, 5.2, 350, 'liquid'],
    ['metmorfin', '2022-01-28', 34, 4.2, 200, 'capsule'],
    ['amoxicilin', '2022-01-29', 24, 3.2, 100, 'injection'],
    ['paracetamol', '2022-01-30', 16, 2.3, 500, 'tablet']
]

# Convert data to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Drug', 'Date', 'Units_Sold', 'Unit_Price', 'Dosage', 'Type'])

# Encode categorical features
encoder = LabelEncoder()
df['Drug'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Drug'])
df['Type'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Type'])

# Normalize numerical features
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df[['Units_Sold', 'Unit_Price', 'Dosage']] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['Units_Sold', 'Unit_Price', 'Dosage']])

# Prepare data for LSTM model
X = df[['Drug', 'Unit_Price', 'Dosage', 'Type']].values
y = df[['Units_Sold']].values

# Reshape X to 3D shape required by LSTM (samples, timesteps, features)
X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1]))

# Get unique drugs in the dataset
unique_drugs = df['Drug'].unique()

# Build a separate LSTM model for each drug
models = {}
predictions = []

for drug in unique_drugs:
    # Filter data for the current drug
    drug_data = df[df['Drug'] == drug]
    
    # Prepare drug-specific data for LSTM model
    X_drug = drug_data[['Drug', 'Unit_Price', 'Dosage', 'Type']].values
    y_drug = drug_data[['Units_Sold']].values
    
    # Reshape X_drug to 3D shape
    X_drug = np.reshape(X_drug, (X_drug.shape[0], 1, X_drug.shape[1]))
    
    # Build the LSTM model for the current drug
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(X_drug.shape[1], X_drug.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    
    # Train the model for the current drug
    model.fit(X_drug, y_drug, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
    
    # Save the trained model
    models[drug] = model
    
    # Make predictions for the current drug
    drug_predictions = model.predict(X_drug)
    
     # Inverse transform predictions using the scaler
drug_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(drug_predictions.reshape(1, -1))

# Append the predictions to the overall predictions list
predictions.extend(drug_predictions.flatten())


# Print the predictions
for i in range(len(df)):
    print(f"Drug: {encoder.inverse_transform([df['Drug'].iloc[i]])[0]}, Predicted Units_Sold: {predictions[i]}")
```

But I'm getting this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17472\1703905132.py in <module>
     69 
     70      # Inverse transform predictions using the scaler
---> 71 drug_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(drug_predictions.reshape(1, -1))
     72 
     73 # Append the predictions to the overall predictions list

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in inverse_transform(self, X)
    527         )
    528 
--> 529         X -= self.min_
    530         X /= self.scale_
    531         return X

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,3)
```

Comment: Why are you applying scaler.inverse_transform on your predictions? (this is wrong). drug_predictions will contain the estimated prices (continuous values).
Also I still don't get it how are you using LSTM with one time_points (X_drug = np.reshape(X_drug, (X_drug.shape[0], 1, X_drug.shape[1]))), it is useless to use any recurrent model under such settings.